# CSS: Force a column to always have full height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have the following html :

```
<div style="height: 80px">
   ...
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col1">...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col2">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both my col1 and my `col2` are currently having `height: auto;` However, my `col2` is always gonna be bigger than my `col1`.
I don't want my `col2` to have a specific height. However, I would like my `col1` to always be full height and so match whatever height `col2` has.

How can I achieve this in css/sass ?

Comment: you can set fix height of column1 & column2

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do this using either `flexbox` or `table`:

```css
.row.equal {
  display: table;
}
.row.equal .column {
  display: table-cell;
  
  /* Just for demo purposes */
  max-width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  background-color: red;
}

.row.equal.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.row.equal.flex .column {
  /* Just for demo purposes */
  max-width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row equal">
  <div class="column">
    Equal height column using the table property
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Equal height
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row equal flex">
  <div class="column">
    Equal height column using the flex property
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Equal height
  </div>
</div>
```

You should be pretty safe without using prefixes, but be sure to check out [caniuse](http://caniuse.com). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

use `display:table-cell` . it will make them same height. 
also use `vertical-align:top` so the text will always be positioned at the top of the col

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/ta45ps1k/)**

css code :

```
.row {
  display:table;
}
.col1,.col2 { 
  display: table-cell;
  width:300px;
  veritcal-align:top;
}
.col1 { 
  background:red
}
.col2 { 
  background:blue;
  height:200px;
}
```